# Call addFirst on a Collection

Tags: java, collections

```
Collection col = new LinkedList();
```

Is there a way to call `col.addFirst` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you cast to `LinkedList`:

```
((LinkedList) col).addFirst(..)
```

But this is discouraged, because you don't always know the concrete type of the collection. You can check with `instanceof`, but that is not good object oriented code. If you really require a `LinkedList`, require a `LinkedList` (rather than `Collection`)

Comment: Discouraged, but really necessary in this case as even `List` doesn't have `addFirst`, only `LinkedList` does.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it is necessary - in case too many preconditions are there and you just can't change the design

Comment: I agree with Daniel - it should be discouraged. He should use LinkedList type for col1 if he has to call addFirst().

Answer (score 3):

If you declare a variable as Collection, this means that you normally plan to consider this variable, in the rest of your program, as a simple Collection, and not as a linked list. The methods offered by the Collection interface should be sufficient for the rest of your program using this variable.

If you need access to a specific method only present in the LinkedList class, then the variable should be a declared as LinkedList.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you need to use Collection in this case, however you can still "program to an interface and not to an implementation" if you use the interface **java.util.Deque** which, by chance, also **extends java.util.Collection**

```
Deque<String> deque = new LinkedList<String>();
deque.addFirst("Hello");
Collection<String> collection = deque;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use List instead of Collection, then the .add() method is available. Add at index 0 to put it in on the first position.

```
list.add(0, object)
```